# How do you pronounce, "pleurisy"?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, rhoticity

According to Wiktionary, pleurisy is pronounced one of two ways:

a) /ˈplʊəɹɪsi/

b) /ˈpljʊəɹɪsi/

I don't hear the /j/ sound when I say the word (in General American) - I hear it like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8V8u6ywxCM

Two questions:

1. In General American, do you hear pleurisy with or without the /j/?
2. If you do hear it as option a (/ˈplʊəɹɪsi/), does that mean the /ʊəɹ/ in pleurisy sounds the same as the /ʊɚ/ in the words "boor, spoor, moor, Moor, poor; boorish"?

Comment: Most American dialects don't use [j] after a consonant cluster before [u].

Comment: Some Americans will pronounce the "eu" with a Y (i.e., IPA /j/) sound at the beginning. They're the same Americans who instead of pronouncing "news" as "nooz," pronounce it as "nyooz," those Americans predominantly being in the North East (including a wide swath that extends as far west as Minnesota), much of the East Coast, Southwestern Florida, and parts of the West Coast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pertains to the second question The *Longman Pronunciation dictionary* has this.

> pleurisy 'plʊər əs i||'plʊr əs i

This means that in BrE jod is not normally used and that in Gen Am not only jod but as well the diphthong disappears. Therefore, what would be a (the) mainstream pronunciation in Gen Am is not as "boor, spoor,…".

Comment: Kudos for consulting a reliable source, but you're mistaking [phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme) for [phones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_(phonetics)). GenAm doesn't have /ʊə/, period. LPD transcribes *boor, spoor*, etc. with "ʊᵊr" because the *realization* may be diphthongal when /ɪr/, /er/ or /ʊr/ is not followed by a vowel, but the *phonological contrast* between e.g. *nearer* and *mirror* doesn't exist in most rhotic North American accents. So it's the same sound as the first vowel in e.g. *spooring* in that accent. (See Wells's *Accents of English* vol. 3, p. 481.)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the first question. Most--if not all--American accents have lost the /j/ after certain coronal consonants so words like *new, lewd, sue, stupid* are pronounced without the /j/. As @herisson explained in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/546774/365490): ‘Words that historically contained /juː/ are typically spelled with *u*, *ew* or *eu*’. *Pleurisy* is spelt with *eu* and has /juː/ in some British accents; however, it's pronounced without the /j/ in most American accents.